# Grails 3 Runtime Automated Database Custom SQL

Tags: database, grails, initialization, customization, grails-3.0

We have a large application with about 100 tables.  We have been updating the database manually between releases.

We also recently switched from **Grails 2** to **Grails 3**.

We now need the Application to (for the first time in a while) create a new Database from scratch, and this is the first time since using Grails 3.

The database is varied enough that it needs some manual runtime customization.

To complicate matters, the application is also using `Quartz`.

The problem is:

**After the Application initializes the tables, but before the Application and Quartz start running, we need to inject this set of custom SQL.  Where is the correct place to insert the SQL?**

I have tried some things like `Application.groovy` and `Bootstrap.groovy`, but have not been able to determine (with Grails 3) the appropriate location to inject this custom SQL.  For example the Quartz tasks are running and attempting to access certain tables, but they have not been "corrected" yet so the app is throwing errors.

**UPDATE**

I tried the following in Bootstrap.groovy

```
Tag.withTransaction {
    String updateSQL = "ALTER TABLE tag DROP COLUMN class;"

    def sql = new groovy.sql.Sql(dataSource)
    sql.executeUpdate(updateSQL)
}

Tag.withTransaction {
    Tag newTag
    newTag = new Tag(name: 'TAG 1').save(flush: true)
}

Tag.withTransaction {
    List tags = Tag.findAll()
    println("===  Tag Size = ${tags.size()}")
}
```

The `executeUpdate()` throws an exception that column `class` cannot be found.

However if I reorder the three sections and use the following:

```
Tag.withTransaction {
    Tag newTag
    newTag = new Tag(name: 'TAG 1').save(flush: true)
}

Tag.withTransaction {
    List tags = Tag.findAll()
    println("===  Tag Size = ${tags.size()}")
}

Tag.withTransaction {
    String updateSQL = "ALTER TABLE tag DROP COLUMN class;"

    def sql = new groovy.sql.Sql(dataSource)
    sql.executeUpdate(updateSQL)
}
```

then the `executeUpdate()` completes successfully (although it is still too late as the Quartz jobs are already running).

I do not understand this at all.

Thank you for the suggestions.  For now I will try the Database Migration Plugin, but would still appreciate other suggestions.

Comment: Can't you put the SQL in Bootstrap and configure Quartz to start after a specified delay?

Comment: You might have a look at the database-migration plugin. http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/1.4.0/  You can set up a grails app to run migrations as part of startup.  You might still have to do what @jnunderwood suggested and have your quartz jobs delay or start based on some grails lifecycle event that happens after you're sure the DB operations are done.

Comment: Could you an initial Quartz Job that would do the customization and that job to start up the other jobs or the other jobs could check a table to see that the customization has been completed.  Still not sure why using Bootstrap did not work but this would be another approach.

Comment: @npskirk: I will try that.  Thank you.

Comment: @Joe: The one drawback to that approach is that the solution could also ideally be used to initialize the Quartz tables if they do not exist.  But I cannot create a Quartz job then to initialize the Quartz tables.